# How do I replace a word on a specific cell upon clicking on an image in another cell that is on the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

How do I replace a word on a specific cell upon clicking on an image in another cell that is on the same row?

This is the code that adds a new row to the table when the form is completed:

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
    var st = '';
    $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select').each(function(){
        st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
        $(this).val('');
    });
    st = st+ '<td>Active</td><td><img class="pencil" src="images/pencil-black.png"></img><img class="lock" src="images/lock-black.png"></img><img class="bin" src="images/bin-black.png"></img></td>';
    $('#tablelist').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
});
```

What I want to be done is upon clicking on the image "lock", it would change the word "Active" to "Blocked"(In bold and red). The problem I am currently facing right now is how do I tell the function to only go through the row the image is in and replace the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work (add the `class="status"` to the `td` with Active in it):

```
$(".lock").click(function () {
   $(this).parent().parent().find(".status").html("Blocked");
});
```

Comment: It works! Thanks alot! But how do i do a toggle? For e.g. when its blocked, i want it to switch to Active.

Comment: You can use `toggleClass("active")` to mark the current state of it, or `data("active")` for the same. You could check the text in the cell too with `html()`

Comment: hmm but if i were to be toggling the class it wouldn't change the text right?

Comment: No, but you can check if it has the class (`hasClass("active")`) in the click handler, so you can set the correct new text.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery, first add class to td containing Text Active, i.e. class="status":

```
$(".lock").click(function(){

  $(".status",$(this).parent().parent()).html("Blocked");
});
```

Comment: It did not work.
I tried my version too and it didn't work either.
`$('#tablelist').on('click', '.lock', function() {
        $(".status",$(this).parent()).html("Blocked");
    });`